# How do I deploy the OpenStack bundle to one machine?

Tags: juju, openstack

Is it possible to deploy the OpenStack bundle to one machine with the CLI?

Is it possible to edit the example.yaml bundle with --to machine?

If yes, how?

Comment: Be sure to mark answers as accepted if they answered your question, or at the very least upvote it if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to modify the bundles .yaml file to include the 'to' directives, I don't have any experience with deploying the Openstack bundle specifically to a single machine however.

An example using 'to':

```
envExport:
  services:
    mysql:
      # The only machine id supported is machine 0
      to: 0
    wordpress:
      units: 3
    redis-server:
      units: 3
      to: [lxc:wordpress, wordpress]
    ceph:
      units: 4
      to: [wordpress, wordpress, wordpress, wordpress]
    serenade:
      to: lxc:wordpress=2
```

You can find more information on the deployer here: http://pythonhosted.org/juju-deployer/config.html#placement

Additional information on deploying bundles from the CLI and the GUI can be found here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-bundles

Answer (score 1):

You can install openstack-in-a-box using [DevStack](http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html).

It is not a production setup, but it is pretty easy to install and get up and running from the CLI.