# juju bundle deploy in one machine in LXC?

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack, lxc

Hi So far i have developed juju charm bundle which contains three charms.I have Two Questions (Q1) And i need to deploy juju charm bundle in one machine in LXC. i have three charms and normally when i deploy charm it deploy in three different machines.I have followed this question([How do I deploy the OpenStack bundle to one machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395923/how-do-i-deploy-the-openstack-bundle-to-one-machine)) and add "to : 0" to each charm in my charm bundle yaml file.Then i got this error.

```
An error occurred while deploying the bundle: cannot assign unit "mysql/0" to machine 0: machine "0" cannot host units
```

So first i want to know is it possible to add all charms in one machine.And if it is possible what is the wrong with my bundle.Here i have attached my bundle.

```
sample:
  services:
    mysql:
      to: 0
      charm: "cs:precise/mysql-27"
      num_units: 1
      annotations:
        "gui-x": "139"
        "gui-y": "168"
    wordpress:
      to : 0
      charm: "cs:precise/wordpress-20"
      num_units: 1
      annotations:
        "gui-x": "481"
        "gui-y": "178"
  relations:
    - - "wordpress:db"
      - "mysql:db"
```

(Q2)And last thing i have seen (http://marcoceppi.com/2014/06/deploying-openstack-with-just-two-machines/) that is it possible to add more charms in to one machine in OpenStack.So this is manual installation with only charms not bundle.I want to know i have one bundle and using juju GUI i want to deploy my bundle in one machine (Because i have only three nodes in my cloud) in OpenStack as well.Is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to append a slight bundle modification below that should get you up and running.

```
sample:
  services:
    ubuntu:
      charm: "cs:trusty/ubuntu"
      num_units: 1
    mysql:
      to: lxc:ubuntu=0
      charm: "cs:precise/mysql-27"
      num_units: 1
      annotations:
        "gui-x": "139"
        "gui-y": "168"
    wordpress:
      to : lxc:ubuntu=0
      charm: "cs:precise/wordpress-20"
      num_units: 1
      annotations:
        "gui-x": "481"
        "gui-y": "178"
  relations:
    - - "wordpress:db"
      - "mysql:db"
```

What I did differently was deploy an ubuntu charm to the canvas which will just deploy an ubuntu host. Nothing fancy - no additional config. From there, i deploy to LXC containers targeted at that host which will warehouse your MySQL and Wordpress instances in LXC - mind you we still haven't resolved reachability from the outside world and this will require a reverse-proxy server, such as haproxy to live on the "ubuntu" node. Not LXC but the parent service.

```
juju deploy cs:trusty/haproxy --to ubuntu/0
```

or if your machine id were #1

```
juju deploy cs:trusty/haproxy --to 1
```

From here you should see 2 total machines consumed (1 for the bootstrap, 1 for the LXC containers + haproxy)